# How to take View and layout on the screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-activity

I try to make a activity and a View on the screen, cause the activity have the buttons which I need. My question is how can I do it, that when I start the app I see the buttons from the activity and the ball and the box from the view class??

How should I take the view in the layout?

that is the activity:

```
 public class GameView extends Activity implements OnClickListener {


        private Button bPAUSE;
        private TextView tvTries;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.gameview);
        initialize();


        }

        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
        public void initialize(){
        bPAUSE = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        bPAUSE.setOnClickListener(this);
        tvTries = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);




    }
    }
```

that the View class:

```
public class BouncingBallView extends View {
 private Ball ball;
 private Box box;

 // For touch inputs - previous touch (x, y)
 private float previousX;
 private float previousY;

 // Constructor
 public BouncingBallView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    box = new Box(0xff00003f);  // ARGB
    ball = new Ball(Color.GREEN);

    // To enable keypad
    this.setFocusable(true);
    this.requestFocus();
    // To enable touch mode
    this.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
 }

 // Called back to draw the view. Also called after invalidate().
 @Override
 protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // Draw the components
    box.draw(canvas);
    ball.draw(canvas);

    // Update the position of the ball, including collision detection and reaction.
    ball.moveWithCollisionDetection(box);

    // Delay
    try {  
       Thread.sleep(30);  
    } catch (InterruptedException e) { }

    invalidate();  // Force a re-draw
 }

 // Called back when the view is first created or its size changes.
 @Override
 public void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldW, int oldH) {
    // Set the movement bounds for the ball
    box.set(0, 0, w, h);
 }



int touchCounter = 2;

 @Override
  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
     float currentX = event.getX();
     float currentY = event.getY();
     float deltaX, deltaY;
     float scalingFactor = 1.0f / ((box.xMax > box.yMax) ? box.yMax : box.xMax);



         switch (event.getAction()) {
         case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

              touchCounter = 2;

    if (currentX >= previousX) {
    deltaX = currentX - previousX;
    ball.speedX += deltaX * scalingFactor;    
   } else if (previousX >= currentX) {
    deltaX = previousX - currentX;
    ball.speedX += deltaX * scalingFactor;  
   } if (currentY >= previousY) {
    deltaY = currentY - previousY;
    ball.speedX += deltaY * scalingFactor;    
   } else if (previousY >= currentY) {
    deltaY = previousY - currentY;
     ball.speedY += deltaY * scalingFactor;
    }


               //vorherig(previous)  - aktuell            

              break;              
         case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:



              touchCounter = 1;

              // Modify rotational angles according to movement
              break;

         }



     // Save current x, y
     previousX = currentX;
     previousY = currentY;
     return true;  // Event handled
  }
}
```

I actually tries to do this in the activity class but the layout is missing...

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    View BouncingBallView= new BouncingBallView(this);
    setContentView(BouncingBallView);
    initialize();


    }
```

Comment: If you want to show a view, it should be in your layout.

Comment: I know, but how can I do this?